# I can't figure out this javascript DOM logic

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this piece of code but I dont understand the presence of:" subTotal = subTotalElement.textContent "

```
function updateSubtotal(product) {
  console.log('Calculating subtotal, yey!');
  // const price
  // const quantity
  const price = product.querySelector('.price span');
  const quantity = product.querySelector('.quantity input');
  const subTotalElement = product.querySelector('.subtotal span'); //HTML element

   

  const subTotal = price.textContent * quantity.value; //input work with  input.value

 subTotal = subTotalElement.textContent ; //to change the HTML
  return subTotal;
}
```

Comment: It's not even valid code, as `subTotal` is a const. There's no point in trying to understand invalid code. Why are you?

Comment: Should probably be `subTotalElement.textContent = subTotal;` because the name of the method is `updateSubtotal()`, and the comment says "to change the HTML".

Comment: @RickardElimää: You're right. So when we have to "updateSubtotal" we have to put subTotal at the end of the equality ?

Comment: @RickardElimää that makes sense. So dodi, the intent seems to be to update an element in the DOM based on the values of two other elements. `updateSubtotal` is probably called in response to an event, e.g. the user entering a new value in the `<input class='quantity'>` field.

Comment: subTotalElement.textContent is trying to get the text of the span element

Comment: Ok thanks @Inigo I get it